# VB2010: Create shortcut on desktop programmatically that runs as administrator

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am using this way below to create shortcuts on user's desktop. I also want them to run as administrator. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132508/visual-studio-run-as-administrator-shortcut), here in StackOverflow but... I want to do the same thing programmatically, not by the hand.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub CreateShortcuts()
    Dim NewDir = AppFolder.Text
    Dim WSH As Object = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    WSH = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Dim MyShortcut, DesktopPath
    DesktopPath = WSH.SpecialFolders("Desktop")

    MyShortcut = WSH.CreateShortcut(DesktopPath & "\Application Controller.lnk")
    MyShortcut.TargetPath = WSH.ExpandEnvironmentStrings(NewDir & "\Application.exe")
    MyShortcut.WorkingDirectory = WSH.ExpandEnvironmentStrings(NewDir)
    MyShortcut.WindowStyle = 1
    MyShortcut.IconLocation = NewDir & "\Application.exe"
    MyShortcut.Save()
End Sub
```

Comment: So you want to bypass security?

Comment: I just want my Application's shortcut to run as administrator...

Comment: There is a difference between running as administrator and trying to run as administrator (the latter will prompt the user for admin info, the former will bypass this). Which are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Sastreen: To run as administrator!

Comment: @Simon I don't think you'll be able to bypass UAC...

Comment: Anyway, thank you guys! I'll do it by editing the manifest file of my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are searching for the 'runas' command. You can say that your command line arguments for the target program is:

```
runas /savecred /user:administrator "yourprogrampathhere.exe"
```

Just make sure that the user named 'administrator' does exist. BTW, there is a flag on the Properties window of the shortcut, I just don't know how to do it with the WShell way, but this solution might work.
This line needs to change:

```
 MyShortcut.TargetPath = WSH.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("runas /savecred /user:administrator """ & NewDir & "\Application.exe""")
```

If you're wondering why I put too many quotation marks, don't worry. They're used to escape the initial quotation mark. Have a wonderful day, and I hope your program will work!

EDIT: Using this will prompt you for an Administrator password. You must have one of that, because empty passwords are not allowed. The password will be saved and won't be prompted again until next system reboot.

Comment: Your welcome! :) If you don't want to save the password, make sure you remove the /savecred from the command.