# Visual Studio 2019 always run as administrator from the task bar icon

Tags: windows, visual-studio, windows-10, visual-studio-2019

I want Visual Studio 2019 on Windows 10 to always run as administrator from the **task bar icon**. I need to run several solutions as administrator, so admin should be the default.

Note: I want to run only 1 solution without admin privileges. For this 1 solution, using the recent solutions list from the taskbar icon works fine.

Related:

- [VS2017 / VS 2019 Run As Admin from Recent solutions list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42723232/vs2017-vs-2019-run-as-admin-from-taskbar). This is close, but I still want 1 solution to not run as admin.
- [Make Visual Studio 2019 Always Run as Administrator from Start Bar Recent Solutions List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57698175/make-visual-studio-2019-always-run-as-administrator-from-start-bar-recent-soluti) This is essentially the same question as above. I flagged as a dup.
- [Visual Studio Run as administrator shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132508/visual-studio-run-as-administrator-shortcut) This is close, but wants a desktop shortcut instead of a taskbar icon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want Visual Studio 2019 on Windows 10 to always run as administrator from the **task bar icon**.

Right-click the Visual Studio icon in your taskbar, or the shortcut on your desktop > right-click Visual Studio 2019 > Properties > Advanced... > Run as administrator > OK > Apply

Now when you open Visual Studio from the taskbar, you should see ADMIN in upper-right corner!

[image: ADMIN in the upper-right corner]

Comment: This was really difficult to find. Thanks for the solution mate